# Unreasonable memory consumption for delta lake on pandas

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, databricks, etl, delta-lake

I am working on Databricks using Delta Lake.

I have a dataset that is approx 1.9GB in size (parquet format). I am trying to convert this dataset to a Delta Table and I was able to successfully create such table with spark without any problems.

This dataset is used in a pretty standard ETL pipeline.

However, in my specific use case (due to some legacy code that works only in pandas), some processing requires pandas, so what I was willing to do is to cast my delta table from spark to pandas using `my_pandas_df = my_delta_table.select("*").toPandas()`.

The code works fine, but I noticed an unreasonable consumption of memory because of this command.

If I read the original parquet dataset with `pandas.read_parquet()` I have this memory footprint on my databricks cluster:
[image: Pandas read parquet memory footprint]

However, if I read the Delta Table with Spark and then cast it to pandas, I obtain this very different memory footprint:
[image: Delta table memory footprint]

As you might notice, the memory consumption is MUCH higher for the same identical dataset. Considering that Delta is using parquet files under the hood, I can't understand why there is such a huge difference in memory consumption for the same identical data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by relying of the [delta-rs](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs) library for python.

I ran the following code:

```
!pip install deltalake # Just to report which library I installed and how

from deltalake import DeltaTable

dt = DeltaTable("path_to_my_table/")
pandas_table = dt.to_pandas()
```

This way I was able to cast a delta table to pandas without having memory leakage and in a reasonable time (8millions rows x 400 columns loaded in 5 minutes).

NB: Be extra careful about partitioning in your underlying parquet files in the Delta table. It highly impacts the performance of the reading!